# Error al recibir datos en una petición GET de Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Necesito poner el siguiente archivo JSON en el siguiente formato article.source, article.authors.map(a=>a.name)).join(',',')} para poder usarlo en un proyecto de VUE.

```js
{
 "30617043": {
  "uid": "30617043",
  "pubdate": "2019 Jan 7",
  "epubdate": "2019 Jan 7",
  "source": "JMIR Mhealth Uhealth",
  "authors": [{
   "name": "Spears CA",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Bell SA",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Scarlett CA",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Anderson NK",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Cottrell-Daniels C",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Lotfalian S",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Bandlamudi M",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Grant A",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Sigurdardottir A",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Carter BP",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Abroms LC",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }, {
   "name": "Wetter DW",
   "authtype": "Author",
   "clusterid": ""
  }],
  "lastauthor": "Wetter DW",
  "title": "Text Messaging to Enhance Mindfulness-Based Smoking Cessation Treatment: Program Development Through Qualitative Research.",
  "sorttitle": "text messaging to enhance mindfulness based smoking cessation treatment program development through qualitative research",
  "volume": "7",
  "issue": "1",
  "pages": "e11246",
  "lang": ["eng"],
  "nlmuniqueid": "101624439",
  "issn": "",
  "essn": "2291-5222",
  "pubtype": ["Journal Article"],
  "recordstatus": "PubMed",
  "pubstatus": "3",
  "articleids": [{
   "idtype": "pubmed",
   "idtypen": 1,
   "value": "30617043"
  }, {
   "idtype": "pii",
   "idtypen": 4,
   "value": "v7i1e11246"
  }, {
   "idtype": "doi",
   "idtypen": 3,
   "value": "10.2196/11246"
  }, {
   "idtype": "pmc",
   "idtypen": 8,
   "value": "PMC6329411"
  }, {
   "idtype": "rid",
   "idtypen": 8,
   "value": "30617043"
  }, {
   "idtype": "eid",
   "idtypen": 8,
   "value": "30617043"
  }, {
   "idtype": "pmcid",
   "idtypen": 5,
   "value": "pmc-id: PMC6329411;"
  }],
  "history": [{
   "pubstatus": "received",
   "date": "2018/06/06 00:00"
  }, {
   "pubstatus": "accepted",
   "date": "2018/10/10 00:00"
  }, {
   "pubstatus": "revised",
   "date": "2018/09/24 00:00"
  }, {
   "pubstatus": "entrez",
   "date": "2019/01/09 06:00"
  }, {
   "pubstatus": "pubmed",
   "date": "2019/01/09 06:00"
  }, {
   "pubstatus": "medline",
   "date": "2019/01/09 06:01"
  }],
  "references": [],
  "attributes": ["Has Abstract"],
  "pmcrefcount": "",
  "fulljournalname": "JMIR mHealth and uHealth",
  "elocationid": "doi: 10.2196/11246",
  "doctype": "citation",
  "srccontriblist": [],
  "booktitle": "",
  "medium": "",
  "edition": "",
  "publisherlocation": "",
  "publishername": "",
  "srcdate": "",
  "reportnumber": "",
  "availablefromurl": "",
  "locationlabel": "",
  "doccontriblist": [],
  "docdate": "",
  "bookname": "",
  "chapter": "",
  "sortpubdate": "2019/01/07 00:00",
  "sortfirstauthor": "Spears CA",
  "vernaculartitle": ""
 }
}
```

Este `JSON` es de una petición **GET** que se hace a la siguiente dirección `https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&rettype=abstract&id=28198679` tengo el siguiente código:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&rettype=abstract&id=28198679"
    }).then(res => {
        var obj = res.data.result;
        delete obj.uids;
        console.log("1");
        console.log(obj);
        this.articles = obj;
        console.log("2");
        console.log(this.articles);
        console.log("3");
        console.log("next");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.articles));
        let data = JSON.stringify(this.articles);
        console.log("4");
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("5");
        //alert(json["source"]);
    }).catch(error => {
        //handle error
        console.log("Error");
    });
  }
})

//article.source, article.authors.map(a=>a.name)).join(',',')}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Axios</title>

     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app">
      {{ info }}
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

El error que tengo es que `this.articles` es unndefined pero entonces no se que hacer para poder almacenar el valor y hacer lo dicho anteriormente

Answer (score 1):

El error `this.articles is undefined` es porque no has declarado `articles` en:

```
...

data () {
    return {
      info: null,
      articles: null
    }
  },

...
```